# How to run php file in cmd on windows

Tags: php

I have set Path variable to follow path to php interpreter. However when i run

php file.php

it prints the content of the file and does not show the wanted result e.g

file contains

```
<? 
echo "Hello world!"
?>
```

and console does not output "Hello world " bu

```
<? 
echo "Hello world!"
?>
```

How to set it up right?

Comment: Have you tried using `<?php` instead of `<?` as the opening tag? You are using Short Open Tags, which are not enabled by default

Comment: Use a proper starting tag: `<?php`

Comment: Have you tried to run the same on going to the specified path where php exists? May be there exist some problem in setting PATH. Also if you type PATH on cmd does it show php path set?